# Why does scroll event not bubble?

Tags: javascript, performance, events, scroll, event-bubbling

Today I've got kind of theoretical question. Why does scroll event not bubble?
Is it connected with performance issues? I did some digging, but unfortunately didn't find any answers that would fulfill my curiosity.

Thanks for your replies :)

Comment: What would you do that would require it to bubble?

Comment: Doesn't it bubble? edit: Oh, you mean when it's not dispatched on the Document.

Comment: @ZachSaucier it'd be great if it bubbled for event delegation

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It bubbles but not on elements. It bubbles at the document object up to document.defaultView (window of the document). This behavior happens to avoid performance issues (scroll events can fire at a high rate).

If you want to learn more about scrolling I would suggest reading the W3 documentation:

https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#scrolling

I hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't bubble to the `window`, nor to `document.defaultView`

Comment: It doesn't bubble, but it _can_ be captured. Set the 3rd argument of `addEventListener` to `true`